# Is there any way using regular expression to capture this group. result should be 2

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```py
import re 

pattern = r'faf'

string = 'fafaf'

print(len(re.findall(pattern, string)))
```

it is giving the answer as 1, but required answer is 2

Comment: Do you want to actually capture the groups, or are you just interested in the number of occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a positive lookahead `r"(?=(<pattern>))"` to find overlapping patterns:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(?=(faf))"
string = "fafaf"
print(len(re.findall(pattern, string)))
```

You can test regexes here: https://regex101.com/r/3FxCok/1